# Why isn't my crontab file executing my node script?

Tags: node.js, cron, jobs, schedule

I have a node script at the following path `/Users/SomeName/Desktop/Personals/auto-stock2/update_contracts.js`

I want to execute this script every 5 minutes, between the hours of 9:30am - 4:00pm on weekdays, here is my cronjob:

```
30-59/5 9     * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/node /Users/SomeName/Desktop/Personals/auto-stock2/update_contracts.js > /var/log/update_contracts_job.log 2>&1
*/5     10-15 * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/node /Users/SomeName/Desktop/Personals/auto-stock2/update_contracts.js > /var/log/update_contracts_job.log 2>&1
0       16    * * 1-5 /usr/local/bin/node /Users/SomeName/Desktop/Personals/auto-stock2/update_contracts.js > /var/log/update_contracts_job.log 2>&1
```

as you see, I provided the absolute path for both node and my script; for whatever reason, the script never runs. I have been checking the `update_contracts_job.log` file to verify this.

Running `crontab -l` from my user directory returns the crontab's contents. I've also run `sudo crontab -u SomeName -l` which also displays the file.

I was able to get some feedback by checking my mail locally:

```
cd /var/mail
cat SomeName
```

The mail body states: `/bin/sh: /var/log/update_contracts_job.log: Permission denied`

Looks to be some type of permissions issue is causing the logs to not be written. I've since removed the portion that writes to the log file  `> /var/log/update_contracts_job.log 2>&1` from my cronjob, and now I am seeing this error

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/Users/SomeUser/Desktop/Personals/auto-stock2/update_contracts.js'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:476:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:377:35)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1090:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:769:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint Äas runMainÅ (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 ä
  errno: -1,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'EPERM',
  path: '/Users/SomeUser/Desktop/Personals/auto-stock2/update_contracts.js'
å
```

Comment: What about after you add a line `DISPLAY=:0` near the top of your crontab.

Comment: I added that to my crontab, not sure what it does, but check original question, I've added additional details.

Comment: We have two crontab one sudo and other one non sudo users, you have added cronjob on non sudo crontab. Add them on sudo crontab.
Also whats the coutput when you simply run:  /usr/local/bin/node /Users/SomeName/Desktop/Personals/auto-stock2/update_contracts.js command?

Comment: I added the cronjob to sudo crontab i believe... i ran `sudo su -` and `sudo crontab -u someuser -e` to modify my cronjob.. also, that command successfully runs my script....

I now get a new error `Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, open '/Users/SomeUser/Desktop/Personals/auto-stock2/update_contracts.js'`

Answer (score 0):

this is because the cron doesn't have full disk access permission. add the cron to full access permission following this article: https://www.hashbackup.com/hashbackup/technical/fulldiskaccess.html